# codeception db module error

Tags: php, laravel, tdd, codeception

I'm trying to create a functional test in codeception where I can check if the database table was pupulated here is the test:

```
<?php 
 $I = new FunctionalTester($scenario);
 $I->am('A guest');
 $I->wantTo('Sign up for an account');

 $I->amOnPage('auth/register');
 $I->fillField('username', 'testuser');
 $I->fillField('first_name', 'test_name');
 $I->fillField('last_name', 'test_last');
 $I->fillField('email', 'test@test.com');
 $I->fillField('password', 'test');
 $I->click('Sign up!');

 $I->seeInDatabase('users', ['username' => 'testuser', 'first_name' => 'test_name', 'last_name' => 'test_last', 'email' => 'test@test.com', 'slug' => 'testuser']);
```

Here is the yaml file:

```
class_name: FunctionalTester
modules:
    enabled: [Filesystem, FunctionalHelper, Db, PhpBrowser]
    config:
      Db:
         dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='db''
         user: 'root'
         password: 'pass!'
         dump: 'tests/_data/dump.sql'
         populate: true
         cleanup: false
      PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://localhost:8000'
```

I get the error :

```
   Couldn't see in database "users",    {"username":"testuser","first_name":"test_name","last_name":"test_last","email":"test@test.com","slug":"testuser"}:
No matching records found
Failed asserting that '0' is greater than 0.
```

however when i fill out the form in the browser the code works and the user is registered

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use `Laravel4/Laravel5` (you didn't mention Laravel version) module and then use [seeRecord](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Laravel4#seeRecord) method. I have the exact same problem with `grabFromDatabase` - it doesn't work but when I'm using `grabRecord` from Laravel module it works fine.